# See the json format of a page

Tags: json

I can see the json format of this [page](https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/recently-launched) using this:

```
https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/recently-launched?format=json
```

but when I try to add the `?format=json` I can't get the same structure with this page

```
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/scparker/we-have-to-go-back-a-lost-parody-musical
```

Why I can't have the same format? I am not familiar with json format so every advice could be helpful for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the second link even offers a JSON view?

Comment: @jwodder I think it because it is the same site.